# Get List of Files checked-out in Visual Source Safe 6.0

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

On a weekly basis, I need to generate a List of Files from my Visual Source Safe 6.0 server, which are in Checked-out State.  The list should provide the Filename and the User ID which has checked-out the file.

Is there any command-line program which I can use to achieve the above objective?  Or is there any external tool/utility to do this job for me?

Comment: Moving this to StackOverflow, since that is the primary area for a lot of source-control questions. I can't recall if it has been asked before, but the community there is very quick to respond.

Answer (score 7):

**From the command line:**

1. `cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe`
2. `SET SSDIR=<path to folder containing srcsafe.ini>`
3. `ss Status $/ -R > checked-out-files.txt`

And then check the contents of checked-out-files.txt for your check-outs.

**For example:**

My `srcsafe.ini` was in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe\MasterDatabase`.

So, my command line looked like this:

1. `cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe`
2. `SET SSDIR=MasterDatabase`
3. `ss Status $/ -R > checked-out-files.txt`

That's it. Easy.

**To get only one user's check-outs:**

[Way to see all files ever checked into Visual SourceSafe by a user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493441/way-to-see-all-files-ever-checked-into-visual-sourcesafe-by-a-user/5197610#5197610)

Answer (score 2):

SS.exe can be used for such purposes. It will  be in the VSS install directory, there are a few configuration steps you need to do to set it up to run conveniently.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ws92cw2%28VS.80%29.aspx

I believe the specific command you are looking for is [Status.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6kac9fd%28VS.80%29.aspx)

e.g. `ss Status $/ -R`

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to do this with vbscript, I have done so in the past but no longer have access to those scripts.

Here is a [link to a post](http://weblogs.asp.net/sjoseph/archive/2005/01/17/354219.aspx) that speaks of doing something similar  to what you want.

Also, here is a [link to a utility](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/ssmonitor.aspx) that gives (mostly) real time change updates by monitoring changes to the journal file.