# Way to see all files ever checked into Visual SourceSafe by a user?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

Is there a way in Microsoft Visual SourceSafe to see all the files I've ever checked-in?

Comment: There's a 2005 version of VSS. I guess its time for me to upgrade. Best Tool Ever.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a project selected, go to Tools, Show History, tick Recursive, and enter your user name into User. Click OK.

Comment: You may have to hold down the shift key when clicking show history to get the dialog that allows you to specify the user. So right click, then shift click on the show history item in the context menu.

Comment: You can also right click the solution node, Show History, then click the Projects... button to get the Recursive box to show.

Answer (score 7):

The command line may be faster, more efficient for this.

**From the command line:**

1. `cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe`
2. `SET SSDIR=<path to folder containing srcsafe.ini>`
3. `ss Status $/ -R -U<username> > checked-out-by-username.txt`

And then check the contents of checked-out-by-username.txt for your check-outs.

**For example:**

My `srcsafe.ini` was in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe\MasterDatabase`.  And my username was `bpaetzke`.

So, my command line looked like this:

1. `cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe`
2. `SET SSDIR=MasterDatabase`
3. `ss Status $/ -R -Ubpaetzke > checked-out-by-bpaetzke.txt`

If you want to get all users' check-outs, remove the `-U<username>` and give the output file a generic name.

**Other command line info:**

- [commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/003ssz4z(VS.80).aspx)
- [options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hsxzf2az(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the details.  Quick question: I am not a VSS Admin, but have Full Control permission on the VSS Database at Root Level.  Will this work?

Comment: @kamleshrao - Not sure. Try it and let us know how it goes.  By the way, these commands are harmless; so, no worries.